# How to make Python search through a text file and print every matching line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, search

Apologies for total noob question. I'm trying to learn Python. I've searched this site and have not found a solution for me. Please let me know if one has already been explained.

I'm trying to make a search program for a list of movie titles in a `.txt` file, and I want it to print every line that contains the words inputted by the user.

For example, if two of the lines in the text file are

```
22. It Happened One Night (1934)
23. Wonder Woman (2017)
```

and the user inputs "on" I would like both of these (and any others) to appear, since both contain the "on" at some point.

I have tried using

```
with open("movies.txt", "r") as f:
     searchlines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if searchphrase in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print(l),
        print
```

but this did not work for me.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with "did not work". Did your code cause an error? Or did you simply not get any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
with open("movies.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

keyword = "on"

filtered_lines = filter(lambda line: keyword.casefold() in line.casefold(), lines)

for line in filtered_lines:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer snippet code bellow

```
def search(text_search):
    with open("movies.txt", "r") as f:
        searchlines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            # if line contains text_search we will print it
            if text_search in line:
                print(line)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    search("One")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I still ran into the problem of it not always working, for example when inputting "wonder", Wonder Woman did not show up

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(text_search):
    with open("movies.txt", "r") as f:
        searchlines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            if text_search.casefold() in line.casefold():
                print(line)
```

Example call your function with: search("ON")

Edited indentation